# Python Selenium Webdriver: How to avoid headless Chrome and run in new window on Windows 10 instead

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I would like to observe what my Selenium webdriver program is doing. However, I currently use headless Chrome and it does not work in its own window. How could I run the program in a window I can see?

This is the code I use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time
def acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) # set browser size.
    # link to data delete form
    print("opening data delete form")
    driver.get("https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8")
    #Select opt out segment: Following option values: "Mail", "Telemarketing", "Email"
    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='OptOutChoices2']/option[@value='Mail']") 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele)
    print("dropdown selected")
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.quit()
    return None
```

When not including following line: `#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "website-functions/acxiom.py", line 46, in <module>
    acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
  File "website-functions/acxiom.py", line 29, in acxiom_DD_formfill
    dropdown_optoutchoice.select_by_value('Myself')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'
alexanderfarr@DESKTOP-4TE1ODA:/mnt/c/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend-web-architecture/github-repos/privacy-api-backend$ python3 website-functions/acxiom.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "website-functions/acxiom.py", line 46, in <module>
    acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
  File "website-functions/acxiom.py", line 15, in acxiom_DD_formfill
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Thank you for your help!

-----------------------**EDIT**--------------------------------------------

When using following code instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time

def acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) # set browser size
    # link to data delete form
    print("opening data delete form")
    driver.get("https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8")
    #Select opt out segment: Following option values: "Mail", "Telemarketing", "Email"

    dropdown=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ss-multi-selected")))
    dropdown.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'ss-option')))
    list_options = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ss-option')
    list_options[2].click()

    print("dropdown selected")
    #Select identity: Following option values: "Myself", "Legal guardian", "Deceased person"
    identity_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('Identity')
    select = Select(identity_dropdown)
    select.select_by_value('Submitter')

    #Select title: Following option values: "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Dr.", "Honorable", "Reverend", "Other"
    title_dropdown=driver.find_element_by_id('Title')
    select = Select(title_dropdown)
    select.select_by_value(title)

    driver.find_element_by_id("FirstName").send_keys(firstname)
    driver.find_element_by_id("MiddleName").send_keys(middlename)
    driver.find_element_by_id("LastName").send_keys(lastname)
    driver.find_element_by_id("DDSuffix").send_keys(suffix)
    driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys(email)
    # KEEP THIS DISABLED BC IT ACTUALLY SUBMITS
    # driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitButton2").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print("executed")
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.quit()
    return None

title = "Mr."
middlename = ""
firstname = "Joe"
lastname = "Musterman"
suffix = ""
email = "joe@musterman.com"
acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
```

I get this error which does not seem to be related to the script itself:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "other/acxiom-test.py", line 64, in <module>
        acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
      File "other/acxiom-test.py", line 21, in acxiom_DD_formfill
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
        desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
        self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session    
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I am unsure how I could fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to an issue in the script, not because of `--headless` mode. It may seem it's because of `--headless` mode but **the root cause** is somewhere else i.e you may notice in the DOM that 'Myself' is the text and not the *value* for the list you wanted to select from.

As a debugging advise, remove the `--headless` option, perform the actions on the page manually and compare with what you instruct the script to do automatically. A correctly implemented script will run the same way headless or not.

Comment: Thank you @0buz! I updated the question which shows that "Myself" / "value" does not seem to be the problem. Maybe could you help me how I could debug the new code or how I could perform the actions manually?

Comment: Just looking at other solutions for "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" error, and I see you already added some of the recommended options. Try also adding `chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")` perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately I still got following error message with your line: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`

Comment: I just noticed you are using `chromium-browser`? Unless you have a particular need for chormium, install/reinstall Chrome instead.

Comment: I would prefer Chrome as well and I use the normal Chrome browser normally in Windows. Since I do not specify in the code to use the  `chromium-browser`, how could I determine that Chrome should be used instead?

Comment: You should probably look at removing chromium-browser from your system. In the meantime, try this in a terminal: `which chromedriver`. The output should be "/usr/bin/chromedriver", unless you've installed it in a virtual environment. Then in your script: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r">>the above output path here<<", chrome_options=options)`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to remove chromium-browser, however, when searching for it, I could not find it on my computer. `which chromedriver` indeed outputs `usr/bin/chromedriver` but when I enter `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"/usr/bin/chromedriver",options=chrome_options)`, I get this error again: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`